# bitbucket pipeline to push commits to another repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, git-hooks

So this is the scenario i have right now, we have a repo (boilerplate) that contains our infrastructure code, docker files, and pipeline scripts, each time we create a new project we copy this repo to a new repo.

the issue is this when we make a change in the boilerplate repo, we have to manually make the change in all our projects and i'd like to automate this process.

is it possible to create a git hook or a bitbucket pipeline to automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have found an answer already, but yes, it is possible.

there are many possible solutions here for the automation tools, but one of the obvious is to create automation code that updates your repositories as needed (for example by using terraform with git provider) and then running this terraform code in bitbucket pipeline on your boilerplate repo.

At this simple scenario - you need to get a list of all repositories that you need to update in some way, by reading it from some file/api or anything else.